# How can I get one villager to plant both carrots and wheat?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I am setting up an auto farm using villagers i only want one villager that will plant wheat and carrots.

Answer (score 1):

What you could do is constantly replace the existing wheat planting villager with another one which plants carrots with the `/execute` command:

Villager #1 is "Rudolf", #2 is "Jelinek":

```
/execute @e[name=Rudolf] ~ ~ ~ summon Villager#2 ~ ~ ~
```

Connected to a comparator:

```
/kill @e[name=Rudolf]
```

A few seconds later:

```
/execute @e[name=Jelinek] ~ ~ ~ summon Villager#1 ~ ~ ~
```

Then (comparator):

```
/kill @e[name=Jelinek]
```

Comment: I know how you chose that names.

Comment: Villagers don't drop items in their inventory when they die, making this method incredibly lossy. Also, you are spawning them with empty inventories, so they'll just go and start planting whatever they find. Assuming you actually manage to spawn a Farmer villager, which is a 1 in 4 chance with your command.

Comment: Forget the last part, I just noticed that any brown-robed villager can farm.